# UnauthoriuzedAccessException when trying to delete some files in Temporary file

Tags: vb.net, access-denied

I'm trying to delete some files in Temporary folder (C:\Windows\Temp), but when i try to debug it, it shows as follow:

I have used Try Statement, but it didin't delete

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Exit.Click

    Try
      'Deletes the temporary file, then exit.
        Delete(Prepare.CorePath)
        Application.Exit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Application.Exit()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Anyone could help or explaining the situation?
PS: I have elevated the app., and it didn't work too.

Comment: Maybe if you gt rid of the Try/Catch the error message would tell you what is wrong

Comment: I've tried that too, it said : "UnauthorizedAccessException"

Comment: You dont have access to `C:\Windows\*` because your app is not Windows.  There are User folders for your temp files

Comment: What does it mean: "your app is not Windows" ? Thanks for your solution, by the way.